# Head First C comparison operation

Tags: c

Right now I am reading Head First C and I have a hard time understanding this piece of code, image taken from the O'Reilly website:

[image]

could you please explain why only single value check is needed in the comparison `val == 10`? The code works but I just do not understand the reason why exactly.

Comment: What is `val` set to if `card_name[0]` is 10, J, Q, or K?

Comment: 10. And the output is "Count has gone down"

Comment: The necessity of only one condition comes down to what the program is supposed to do.  Looks like a blackjack Card Counting algorithm.

Comment: Aside: "There are a few ways of writing this condition". There are, and you should use the same values as those in the comment. `if(val >= 3 && val <= 6)`

Comment: You shouldn't be using atoi, use strtol instead. This program will needlessly crash & burn if another letter than the expected ones are entered. That's not how you should teach newbies C, Mr "head first".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the previous if-else tree, `val` would be set to 10 for each card J, Q or K and also for the card with the value 10. So whenever you had a J, Q, K or 10 `val` would be 10 and so you can just check for this value when checking for these cards.

Answer (score 2):

Check the values of `val` when input is `K`, `Q`, or `J`, they all are equal to `10`, the logic only cares if it is either of those 4 cards or not, thus only `val == 10`